# C# Saving Live Chart to PNG in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, livecharts

I am having difficulties in exporting LiveCharts PieChart to a .png file.

So far what I have done is trying to draw the control to a bitmap ([DrawToBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=net-5.0)), but it is just outputting a black image. I have discarded other alternatives such as screenshots because the chart is not created to be deployed in a custom form for visualization. Its main purpose is just graphic statistic exporting.

This is my main code:

```
LiveCharts.WinForms.PieChart chart = initializePieChart2DFolder(true);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(chart.Width, chart.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
chart.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
bmp.Save("graphFolder.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

This is the method I use to create the Pie chart:

```
private LiveCharts.WinForms.PieChart initializePieChart2DFolder()
{
     LiveCharts.WinForms.PieChart chart = new LiveCharts.WinForms.PieChart();
     chart.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
     chart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 56);
     chart.Name = "pieChart2DFolder";
     chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(364, 250);
     chart.TabIndex = 0;
     chart.BackColorTransparent = false;
     chart.BackColor = Color.White;
     chart.ForeColor = Color.Black;
     SeriesCollection chartData = new SeriesCollection();
     foreach(var annot in numAnnotsPerLabel)
     {
          System.Windows.Media.Color newColor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(color[annot.Key].A, color[annot.Key].R, color[annot.Key].G, color[annot.Key].B);
          chartData.Add( new PieSeries { Title = annot.Key,
                                         Values = new ChartValues<int> { annot.Value },
                                         DataLabels = true,
                                         Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.DimGray,
                                         Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
                                         FontSize = 9,
                                         Fill = new 
         System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(newColor)});
     }
     chart.Series = chartData;
     DefaultLegend customLegend = new DefaultLegend();
     customLegend.BulletSize = 15;
     customLegend.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
     customLegend.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
     customLegend.FontSize = 10;
     chart.DefaultLegend = customLegend;
     chart.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Right;
     var tooltip = chart.DataTooltip as DefaultTooltip;
     tooltip.SelectionMode = LiveCharts.TooltipSelectionMode.OnlySender;
     return chart;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Maybe you have to force the chart to render once before making the bitmap (That is, `DrawToBitmap` might not actually be doing drawing, but just copying from an internal bitmap used for double-buffering)

Comment: In particular, I am suggesting to try calling `chart.Refresh()` before `DrawToBitmap()`

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah I have already try it, but nothing changed :(

Comment: See the last post here: [Chart to Image - Issue #243](https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/issues/243), which uses the same method shown in the GitHub repo where you can find many other examples: [ChartToImageSample](https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/blob/master/Examples/Wpf/CartesianChart/Chart%20to%20Image/ChartToImageSample.xaml.cs). This charting library for WinForms is clearly a WPF wrapper, so `RenderTargetBitmap()` is a more *natural* way to render the content. It also appears that you need to suspend any animation. before rendering the Image.

Comment: @Jimi thank you very much! This is the correct solution. Just notice that you have to use LiveCharts.Wpf instead of LiveCharts.WinForms for saving.

Comment: Yep, you need to reference that assembly directly; but, as in the example posted in the first link, it's used in an extension method, which is pretty good. -- I assume your app is already DpiAware...